# Take photo with custom resolution from CaptureElement with MediaCapture

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps

I'm displaying the camera feed im my Windows Store App using the CaptureElement. Now I'd like to capture a photo as a stream when the user taps the display, which I got working using the code below. Unfortunatly the image returned only has a resolution of 640 x 360, however the camera (Surface RT) can take images with 1280x800, which I'd like to do.

I tried setting

```
        encodingProperties.Height = 800;
        encodingProperties.Width = 1280;
```

but that didn't work. So how do I change the resolution?

```
   private async void captureElement_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var encodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        //encodingProperties.Height = 800;
        //encodingProperties.Width = 1280;
        WriteableBitmap wbmp;

        using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await captureMgr.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(encodingProperties, imageStream);
            await imageStream.FlushAsync();
            imageStream.Seek(0);
            wbmp = await new WriteableBitmap(1, 1).FromStream(imageStream);
        }

        capturedImage.Source = wbmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to come by this and also get rid of the dreaded "HRESULT: 0xC00D36B4" error, partly thanks to the code found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/751b8d83-e646-4ce9-b019-f3c8599e18e0

I made some adjustments, that's why I repost my code here

```
    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    DeviceInformationCollection devices;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        this.mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        if (devices.Count() > 0)
        {
            await this.mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = devices.ElementAt(1).Id, PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview });
            SetResolution();
        }  
    }


    //This is how you can set your resolution
    public async void SetResolution()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> res;
        res = this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
        uint maxResolution = 0;
        int indexMaxResolution = 0;

        if (res.Count >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
            {
                VideoEncodingProperties vp = (VideoEncodingProperties)res[i];

                if (vp.Width > maxResolution)
                {
                    indexMaxResolution = i;
                    maxResolution = vp.Width;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Resolution: " + vp.Width);
                }
            }
            await this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, res[indexMaxResolution]);
        }
    }
```

Though taking photos, make sure you always work with .VideoPreview, not .Photo!

Comment: after this surface pro 2 starts lagging.