# Windows 10 Mobile QR Code Reader

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have an UWP app which scans QR Codes using the `MediaCapture` class and previewing it with a `CaptureElement`. It works completly fine on desktop devices but when I try it on Windows 10 Mobile everytime a photo is taken, the preview displays the this photo for a few seconds before returning to the video preview which makes it look stuttering.
I just want a nice video preview without the user noticing when photos are taken.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem with Win8Rt, in Win10 you should have a better API,  [GetPreviewFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578754/winrt-extract-frames-from-video-stream). not sure if it will help you since I haven't done any Win10.